# Matlab how to call function m.file from callback function that locate in another m file?

Tags: matlab

i have  that function  that locat in +Time folder

```
 function pickdate(handler,jPanel)

 end
```

and in another m file i have callback function

```
uicontrol('parent', grid,...
'Style','popup',...
'unit','normalized',...
'String',datestr(now,'mm/dd/yyyy'),...
'tag','pickdateto',...
'callback',{'Time.pickdate',jPanel});
```

how can i call that function and pass jPanel parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a cell array that contains the function handle (you can [create a handle to a function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html?searchHighlight=function%20handle) by adding an `@` to it) and the arguments (See MATLAB [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/callback-definition.html?searchHighlight=callback%20definition)). And you need to pass two arguments for the sample codes provide above because that's how your function is defined.

```
...'callback',{@Time.pickdate, handler, jPanel});
```

Answer (score 0):

in the function you need three variable like this:

```
function pickdate(handler,event,jPanel)

end
```

and the callback look like this :

```
 'callback',{@Time.pickdate,jPanel});
```

now its work!